# TextWriter is not writing to disk, with no error

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, streamwriter, disk-io

I have the following snippet of code, which takes lines from a List and writes them off to disk:

```
List<string> messages; // a list full of lines of text to write to file
using (System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stSessionStatusFile, true))
{
   int i = 0;
   while (i < messages.Count)
   {
      string line = messages[0];
      writer.WriteLine(line);
      writer.Flush();
      messages.RemoveAt(0);
   }
}
```

However... the resulting file is not created on disk, nor are there any exceptions thrown. It's like the text to write to disk just disappears into thin air. This code works in another assembly, just not in the service that I ported it to. I have no idea why the text wouldn't be written to disk in this case, many thanks for any help with solving this problem.

Comment: How do you know there's no error? It could be throwing an exception on instantiating the `StreamWriter` and moving on without any of the loop executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted and everything started working as expected. I don't really have an explanation as to what happened, but I'd guess that my PC is the issue here, not coder error. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using `File.WriteAllLines`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx.  My experience it's much cleaner for these types of operations.  Helps narrow down the potential for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `i` is not incrementing. Do `i++` inside the loop. Also do this. foreach line, write line, outside the loop flush. also remove the removeat

```
foreach(string line in messages) {
  writer.WriteLine(line)
}

writer.Flush();
```

Comment: No, I've stepped through using the debugger and the code in the while loop seems to execute as intended. As I want to remove the items in List<string> messages as they are written to disk, I opted to use a while loop instead of the foreach loop so I could alter the collection while in the loop. I'll try moving the Flush outside of the loop and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Youse ``StreamWriter`` instead and don't need the flush. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the credential that you used to run the service ... Maybe you could try writing into some temp folder (e.g. C:\Temp) and see if it works